# Atom apm show package config information

Tags: packages, atom-editor, configuration-managment

I am currently trying to set up Atom's linter-eslint as per instructions [here](https://hackernoon.com/set-up-eslint-in-atom-83dfb3d34fdf).

Whilst the tutorial cites a settings page for the **linter-eslint** I receive no such thing. Perhaps all the config is no longer required but this is my first time setting up a linter in a toolchain so I don't really fully understand everything; I am trying to learn (I am following a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4ZIJgOWj_A&t=313s) where they use vscode instead of Atom)

In [this github issue](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/773) I can see that people are able to print a log which contains Atom lots of helpful information about Atom generally and package settings which are described in the tutorial, but I can't see an option that would provide me this with apm - does anyone know what I am missing here?

Just to evidence my lack of a GUI settings option:
[package list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkDjm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a package's setting page, follow these steps:

1. Open your Atom settings
2. Click on the *Installed Packages* tab
3. Search for the packate, e.g. `linter-eslint`
4. Click on the *Settings* button

[image]

The programmatic equivalent is `atom.workspace.open("atom://config/packages/linter-eslint")`, which also works from Atom's console.

Also, the [package-settings](https://atom.io/packages/package-settings) package lets you open any settings page from the command palette.

Comment: Just added an edit to show the lack of that GUI option for me - the Atom console command shows promise though, I currently use Platformio IDE Terminal, can I enter this directly or should I use another Atom console?

Comment: The console from the Google Developer Tools, accessible through Atom's *View > Developer* menu or the shortcut (Cmd+Option+I on macOS).

Comment: Thankyou! Works like a charm and mysteriously now I am in the settings page **spooky noises**